# Activity not Found Exception : using broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am using the following code to start my main activity by dialing a secret code `*#*#8099#*#*`. I have implemented a broadcast receiver for handling the intent. Following is the code.

```
public class SecretCodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String sidv_ = "sidv_";
private static final String SECRET_CODE_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String host = intent.getData() != null ? intent.getData().getHost() : null;

            if (SECRET_CODE_ACTION.equals(action) && "8099".equals.(host)) {
    Log.e(sidv_ , "in onReceive :: secret code receiver");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i); 
            }
    }
}
```

The code for the main acitivity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is the main activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.sidvsharma.autohideapp.MainActivity.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
   }
}
```

the package name is `com.sidvsharma.autohideapp` and the class name in my manifest file is `com.sidvsharma.autohideapp.MainActivity`.

I am getting a activity not found exception for MainActivity.

Following is the manifest file :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sidvsharma.autohideapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".SecretCodeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"/>
        </intent-filter>    
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: did you declare your receiver to manifest file?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan yes i have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forget to add the **data** tag in your **intent-filter** specification.
Here is what you should write to make your ScretCodeReceiver respond to the **`*#*#8099#*#*`** secret code.

```
<receiver android:name=".SecretCodeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
        <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="8099" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```